# Performance Testing Neo4J

Tags: performance, neo4j

Roughly speaking, I am pulling down Twitter into Neo4j. I pull in a user and all their friends. Naturally, the goal is to make this as fast as possible. Unfortunately after the neo4j gets above about 25K nodes, insertion gets really slow. With my best algorithm so far it gets as slow as about 10 relationships per second. Since the average Twitter user that I'm seeing has about 200 friends, this means 20seconds to pull down an individual and all of their friends. How can I bump that up considerably?

[Here are my tests to this point.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/JnBrymn/9685567)

Comment: What about transaction management? Does everything run in one transaction or is it one transaction per insert?

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll have to try that as well.

Comment: If you're looking into doing everything over REST, you can also look at doing batch operations to remove some HTTP overhead (req/resp for every single CYPHER statement).

Comment: One way to dramatically improve the performance would be to do the insertion via Java API, either using the embedded mode or a server extension.

Comment: Hey John, just a quick heads up: You have a syntax error in your `CREATE CONSTRAINT` it contains a dot that doesn't belong there. The exception is swallowed. With the constraint in place it goes down to 3-10s for the whole test: `time:6.519466s; relationship count:39704; node count9902; rel/sec:6090.069340; node/sec:1518.836052`

Answer (score 1):

just a quick heads up:

You have a syntax error in your CREATE CONSTRAINT it contains a dot that doesn't belong there.

The exception is swallowed.

With the constraint in place it goes down to 3-10s for the whole test:

```
time:6.519466s; relationship count:39704; node count9902; 
                rel/sec:6090.069340;      node/sec:1518.836052
```